# How do I get utilization information from my VMWare ESX server for CPU, Memory and Network usage?

Tags: performance, vmware-esx, vmware-server

Does VMWare ESX server have anything built in that I can view CPU, Memory and Network utilization? We have a single VMWare ESX server that we are trying to understand better how our VM's are performing and what changes we might need to make.

Answer (score 2):

The VSphere fat client and web client both have this; it's point-in-time, showing you current numbers. If you need to track that, you'll need some sort of monitoring suite. VRops, VeeamOne, SolarWinds - heck, anything that can speak SNMP can track whatever OID you point it to.